# Random position outside a box that is inside the circle

Tags: c++, random

I need to find a random position outside a box but is inside a circle.
Basically the random position between the the box and the circle.

What I think of  doing is to just rand() a position inside a circle and check whether the position is outside the box, basically doing a collision check.

Is there a more efficient way than this method?

Comment: Please do not close this - it's not a "write code for me" question, it's an algorithm question.

Comment: What are the relative sizes of the circle and the square ? If the square inside the circle is half the area of the circle, then on average the collision method doubles the number of operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the center of the box and circle are coincident, an efficient way you could do this so that you'd only have to generate a random number twice would be:

1. Randomize the angle to project from the circle's origin [0, 2pi]
2. Compute the minimum allowable radius you can generate based on where the geometric ray from the circle's center at the angle generated in step 1 intersects the box.
3. Generate a random number [0, (cirlce's radius - radius from step 2)]

   - This can be done using `%` or `fmod`

If the shape centers are not coincident, you can modify this slightly by separating step 2 into 2 steps:

1. Compute the first intersection with the box (if it exists)
2. Compute the second intersection with the box (if it exists)

and step 3 into 2 steps

1. If 2 intersections were found, generate a random number [0,1] to select either the first or the second valid range (center to first intersection or second intersection to circle's edge)
2. Generate a random number within the selected range.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I would be concerned with the distribution of positions with these solutions. For example, if the random angles chosen have uniform distribution your resulting distribution would be much denser along lines near the rectangle's corners and much sparser along lines near the center of the rectangle's sides.

Comment: Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: If two intersections are found this gives two possible line segments. You should select which one with a possibility weighed by their lengths. Otherwise a great algorithm.

Comment: Michael Surette, That's a great suggestion.
@FrançoisAndrieux, Michael's proposal would help alleviate the distribution concern you identified. No?

Comment: @PipSqueak Consider a uniform sample of angles at some resolution, let's say for simplicity 8 possible line directions with exactly 100 samples each. So the lines will contain 100 points along the line segment that stretches from the edge of the rectangle to the edges of the circle. The four lines that are axis aligned will spread those points over a longer segment (the distance from the square's edge to the circle's perimeter is longer) while the lines that go through the corners will spread those 100 points over a shorter segment. Therefore the density near the corners will be higher.

Comment: @PipSqueak This will hold for any line direction you choose. Those near the corners will have less room in which to distribute positions, and if line direction is homogeneous then all lines will, on average, have to fit the same number of points into it's respective line segment.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, that makes sense. Thanks for explaining. :)
Do you have a proposal to alleviate this concern?

Comment: @PipSqueak There is also the concern that using polar coordinates means that the distribution of positions will be sparser near the edges of the circle and denser near the center.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux in other words it seems that you would have to also weigh the angle by how many points the square cuts out.

Comment: @PipSqueak No, sorry. It's actually pretty tricky to get homogeneous distributions in complex shapes without sampling from simpler areas. Your solution is fine if the distribution doesn't matter, I just wanted to point out a possible limitation.

Comment: @MichaelSurette That's possible, but it get's harder with rectangles that aren't centered on the circle, specially if you have partial overlap. Though I'm sure it could be done.

Comment: Note that you can fix the problem with polar coordinate distribution (ignoring the rectangle) by taking the square root of the random radius (assuming it is between 0 and 1). [Example](http://www.anderswallin.net/2009/05/uniform-random-points-in-a-circle-using-polar-coordinates/).